# How can I insert list of DataGridView rows into SQL table and keep them tracked?

Tags: c#, sql

I am designing Point Of Sale software and I am new to SQL and C#.

[image: screenshot]

As shown in screenshot and according to my code, I use `DataGridView` to list the customer order details and then I click "Save Order" to save the Customer information and the Order details. I used the combination of Order_Number and DateTime as for each customer to save their order details so I can find these details later.

I use two tables: one to store List of all orders with primary key ( Order_Number column) and the other to store Order Details and this table does not have primary or foreign keys.

Until now when I click "Save Order" everything is fine and all data is stored as I wanted. But the problem comes when I want to update the a customer order details. For example I want to update the 3 rows of order#5 and at this point I can not do this because the 3 rows in Order Details has nothing unique that can help me to identify the row3 which one is first row and which one is the last.

The update process should be something like:

`Row 1` in order#5 in Order Details table = `Row 0` in `DataGridView`

`Row 2` in order#5 in Order Details table = `Row 1` in `DataGridView`

`Row 3` in order#5 in Order Details table = `Row 2` in `DataGridView`

But again I can not identify the 3 rows in Order Details table.

I think something is wrong with tables design but as I said I am new to SQL and I do not know how can I store the customer order details and update it later. Anyone knows any idea how to achieve this? please help me.

```
private void SaveOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int OrderNumber;
        DateTime OrderDateTime ;
        OrderDateTime = DateTime.Now;


////This query to save order number and customer information. I used Order_Number as Primary key.


          SqlConnection cn0 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");
         Cn0.Open();

        SqlCommand cm0 = new SqlCommand("Insert into List_of_All_Orders (Phone, DateTime, address ) values ( @Phone, @DateTime, @Address)");


        cm0.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.BigInt);
        cm0.Parameters["@Phone"].Value = textBox1.Text;

        cm0.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
        cm0.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = OrderDateTime;  

        cm0.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cm0.Parameters["@Address"].Value = textBox2.Text;

         cm0.Connection = cn0;
         cm0.ExecuteNonQuery();


//Next query finds the current order number (by counting rows of List of Orders table) so I can use it as identifier later when I save order details

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM List_of_All_Orders")           
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cm);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);

            OrderNumber= dt.Rows.Count;

////////next query saves the the order details (I use Order_Number + DateTime as ID so I know where to find this order details///////////

        int RowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
        int  RowIndex = RowCount - 1;
        SqlConnection cn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PCN-TOSH;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=True");

        cn1.Open();


             for (i = 0; i <= RowIndex; i++)
             {


                 SqlCommand cm1 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Customer_Order_Details (Order_Number, DateTime, Qty,Description, Price ) values (@OrderNumber, @DateTime, @Qty,@Description, @Price)");

                 cm1.Parameters.Add("@OrderNumber", SqlDbType.Int);
                 cm1.Parameters["@OrderNumber"].Value = OrderNumber;

                 cm1.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                 cm1.Parameters["@DateTime"].Value = OrderDateTime;

                 cm1.Parameters.Add("@Qty", SqlDbType.Int);
                 cm1.Parameters["@Qty"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;

                 cm1.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Text);
                 cm1.Parameters["@Description"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;

                 cm1.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money);
                 cm1.Parameters["@Price"].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;

                 cm1.Connection = cn1;
                 cm1.ExecuteNonQuery();



             }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest a simple database table fix:

**Items** table

```
ItemID      - int (primary key)
Name        - varchar
Price       - decimal
Description - varchar
```

**Users** table

```
UserID      - int (primary key)
Name        - varchar
Address     - varchar
Phone       - char
```

**Orders** table

```
OrderNo      - int (primary key)
OrderDate    - datetime
Status       - varchar (Pending, Processing, Completed, etc.)
```

**OrderDetails** table

```
RecordID      - int (primary key)
OrderNo       - int (foreign key)
UserID        - int (foreign key)
ItemID        - int (foreign key)
Quantity      - int (number of items)
Amount        - decimal (item price x quantity)
Timestamp     - datetime
```

EDIT: I included a sample form layout I just created few minutes ago:

[image]

You should create a form which allows you to order multiple items per order. In this form, there should be combo box controls that displays a list of items available (from your Items table) and list of existing user / customer, respectively. There should also be a text box control (that only accepts positive values).

There should be a button that allows you to insert the record to your OrderDetails table. This process will allow you to "keep" your item details before you complete your order. Perhaps you can tag the order number as 0 (or keep it null if allowed).

You can also create a validation which allows you to update the quantity (and the total amount to be paid) or delete an item from your order details.

Lastly, there should be a button control that allows you to "finalize" your order. The button should be able to insert a new record from your orders table. After the insertion, you should be able to update the existing records from the order details table then "tagged" the last recorded order number.

I hope the pseudo code helps. I might lend a hand if you were able to fix your work first :)